# Properties of a Semi-modulo! operation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be an integer with its representation in base $p$ ($p$ may be prime number but not necessarily) described as:
$$A=(a_ma_{m-1}\ldots a_1a_0)_{p}$$
We know $A\equiv (a_n\ldots a_1a_0)_{p}\pmod {p^n} $ , $m\geq n$.

I'm interested in defining a new semi-modulo operation as follows:
$$ A\equiv (a_ma_{m-1}\ldots a_{m-n})_{p} \pmod {p^n}'  , m\geq n $$

We also know that the  algebraic  equation associated  with  the  recurrence $$X_{n+k}+ a_1X_{n+k-1}+a_2X_{n+k-2}+\cdots+a_{k}X_{n}=a$$ is

$$F(x)=x^k+a_1x^{k-1}+\cdots+a_k=0$$

Can this equation be decomposed into  prime  functions $\phi_i(x)\pmod  p'$?

$$F(x)\equiv\phi_1(x)^{e_1}\phi_2(x)^{e_2}\ldots\phi_r(x)^{e_r} \pmod {p}'$$

Does it have the same properties as modulo $p$ operation, for example in studying periodicity of Linear Recurring Sequences $\pmod {p^n}'$?

And how can I apply theorem of Dedekind to it?

---

Hints:

1. I choose (mod)' as a symbol of the new operation. I couldn't figure out whether this operation is defined in number theory before.
2. I think defining such operation may be useful in analyzing binary arithmetic (such as multiplication) of fractional numbers in which $p=2$.